# EXCEL VBA - Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently developing a function that will search for the row number based on a string input that I have. In the following function however I get the error as stated in the title and i have no idea what to do about this :L

Here is the Find Row Function

```
Function MPNTRowECU(ByVal ECUVariantName) As Range

    Debug.Print ECUVariantName

    Dim wsMPNT As Worksheet
    Set wsMPNT = Worksheets("Module Part Number Tracker")

    MPNTRowECU = wsMPNT.Range("C:C").Find(What:=ECUVariantName, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

End Function
```

The Debug.Print line is there to make sure that ECUVariantName is indeed a string and it does return the string that i have everytime. At the MPNTRowECU is where I get the error. Any suggestions guys? Fairly new to VBA

Comment: You need to use `Set` with object variables: `Set MPNTRowECU = `

Comment: @Rory Ah, see I did that earlier and i was getting some other error which is why I was so confused and asked this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Function code below, instead of returning the `Range`, I modifed your `Function` to return the `Row` number (as described in your post).

Also, you need to make sure, that `Find` is successful , by using the `If Not MPNTRng Is Nothing Then` criteria.

***Code***

```
Function MPNTRowECU(ByVal ECUVariantName) As Long

    Dim MPNTRng As Range
    Debug.Print ECUVariantName

    Dim wsMPNT As Worksheet
    Set wsMPNT = Worksheets("Module Part Number Tracker")

    Set MPNTRng = wsMPNT.Range("C:C").Find(What:=ECUVariantName, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)        
    If Not MPNTRng Is Nothing Then ' confirm that Find was successful
        MPNTRowECU = MPNTRng.Row
    Else ' Find failed to find "ECUVariantName"
        MPNTRowECU = -10000 ' just put a high negative value to raise an error
    End If

End Function
```